# Easiest way to connect with PuTTY to an existing docker container

Tags: shell, ssh, docker

Often I come across this situation:

- I have an existing docker container, running a certain service, usually set up from a Dockerfile from Github, etc., usually based on Ubuntu
- I am able to run commands inside this container (with `docker exec` or by setting an entrypoint), including `sh`
- Interactive commands like `vi`, `nano`, `aptitude` or `mc` don't work, because of the buggy terminal of Docker Toolbox - with errors ranging from [defective arrow keys](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/490) over garbled characters to plain [crashes](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22345).

Now the question:
Can I run anything inside my container to connect to a machine with a proper terminal? For example I could SSH into the docker host, so maybe I can run something there that the container can connect to?

I tried mosh, but it seems the mosh client does not run a shell by itself, but instead tries to forward to sshd, which the container doesn't have.

Answer (score -1):

Docker is used to create light weight containers that can run a service with as minimal resources as possible. In addition, docker does not limit what code, apps or utilities you would want to run. That being said, if you are trying to connect to the container as you would to other linux servers, via ssh, you would need to be sure that the docker instance contains and is running an ssh server such as openssh-server and that you expose the port, normally port 22, when you execute the 'docker run' command.

Comment: Actually, even though you haven't given the direct great expected answer, I think that's a good idea...it makes sense during development and testing.